# Don't call onDisconnect() on page refresh in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have used this code to update the online/offline status of the current logged in user where `z` is the userid.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/"+z);
    ref.update({
       online: "1"
    });
    ref.onDisconnect().update({
      online: "0"
    });
```

And I have created another reference that checks whether user is online offline/online. here `oid` is other user's userid.

```
db = firebase.database().ref().child("users/"+oid);
       db.on('value', function(snapShot){
          var data = snapShot.val();
          if(data.online === "0")
          {
              var lastvisible = getTime(data.lastvisibleat);
              var div = $("[data-conli-id="+cid+"]");
              if(div.hasClass('online'))
              {
                  div.removeClass('online');
                  div.addClass('offline');
                  div.find("#user-status-li").attr("data-lv", lastvisible);
              }
              else if(div.hasClass('offline'))
              {
                  div.find("#user-status-li").attr("data-lv", lastvisible);
              }
              var chat_box_div = $("#chat-box-"+cid);
              if(chat_box_div)
              {
                  var user_status_div = chat_box_div.find("#user-status");
                  if(user_status_div.text() === 'online')
                  {
                     user_status_div.text('offline');

                     user_status_div.text(lastvisible+" ago");
                  }
              }
          }
          else if(data.online === "1")
          {
              var div = $("[data-conli-id="+cid+"]");
              if(div.hasClass('offline'))
              {
                  div.removeClass('offline');
                  div.addClass('online');
              }
              var chat_box_div = $("#chat-box-"+cid);
              if(chat_box_div)
              {
                  var user_status_div = chat_box_div.find("#user-status");
                  if(user_status_div.text() === 'offline' || user_status_div.text() !== 'online')
                  {
                     user_status_div.text('online');
                  }
              }
          }
       });
```

This works fine for me. If a browser crashed or the internet is gone or if the user logs out. The problem is when user refreshes the current page or navigates to the other page.

This code which is in a JS file, is reloaded, and the user is on the other side to see the user offline though he has just refreshed it.

Is there any workaround with `onDisconnect()` without having some CRON job?

Comment: That sounds weird. The `onDisconnect()` code looks good. Can you reproduce this in a jsbin, so I can have a look at it?

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot disclose the firebase url @FrankvanPuffelen . Moreover, what happens when I refresh my page the `onDisconnect()` is called. Which I don't want to. Thats's the simplest way I can question.

Comment: When you refresh the page, the current content unloads. So the client disconnects. There is (nor should there be) no way to suppress that. Btw: if you're worried about sharing your URL, you can set up a separate project for this purpose. I use `https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com` for all such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `setInterval()` to update a value in Firebase every 2 minutes. And then have used a CRON job to check the timelapse and set the user offline accordingly.

```
setInterval(function() {
   var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/"+z);
   var d = new Date().today();
   ref.update({
      lastactivityat: d
   });
}, 120000);
```

On server the CRON PHP script. Here I get `$userid` from my MySQL database table.

```
$user_data = $firebase->get('/users/'.$userid."/lastactivityat");
$user = json_decode($user_data, true);
if(count($user) != 0)
{
    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $userLastActivity = date($user);
    $timeLapse = ($currentDate - $userLastActivity)/60;
    if($timeLapse > 5)
    {
        $firebase->set('/users/'.$userid.'/lastvisibleat', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $firebase->set('/users/'.$userid.'/online', '0');
    }
}
```

And this works perfectly and efficiently with decent server config.

Answer (score 1):

Since onDisconnect() is a server side operation, and the connection to the server is severed any time a page is unloaded, the simple answer here is no: you can't prevent the onDisconnect() from firing when the client is disconnected.

What you could do instead, is delay the response to the onDisconnect() event and see if it reconnects within a reasonable threshold (e.g. 10s). If it doesn't, you could then show the user as offline.

A second alternative for more elegant app design would be to utilize [a routing tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-router-plugin) and convert your code to a single page application, where connections don't necessarily need to be severed to show new content.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem and also tried @prashant0205 's answer. But running CRON and calling firebase continuously does not seem a proper solution.
What I have tried is to put a delay on opposite side for updating UI. That is, if **User-A** refreshes the page and goes offline with `onDisconnect()` method, I don't change **User-A** 's staus at **User-B**'s side immediately. On delay of 10 seconds, I call user node again and if it's still `0` then I show him/her offline.

**Note:** I have used `once` in delay method to avoid multiple bindings!

```js
/*Listen user's firebase node*/
function listenUser (user_id) {
 var dbUserRefObj = firebase.database().ref().child("USERS/"+user_id);
    var recentUserData = '';

    dbUserRefObj.on("value",function(snapshotUser){
        if(snapshotUser.exists() == true){
            recentUserData = snapshotUser.val();

            if(typeof recentUserData.status != 'undefined' && recentUserData.status == 1){
                //Online
            }else{
                /*Put delay before showing offline*/
               
                offlineDelay (user_id)
            }

        }else{
            //offline
        }
    });
}

/*Firebase offline delay function*/
function offlineDelay (user_id) {
 /*If user status does not changes in 10 seconds, mark as offline*/
 setTimeout(function () {
  var dbUserRefObj = firebase.database().ref().child("USERS/"+user_id);
     var recentUserData = '';

     dbUserRefObj.once("value",function(snapshotUser){
         if(snapshotUser.exists() == true){
             recentUserData = snapshotUser.val();

             if(typeof recentUserData.status != 'undefined' && recentUserData.status == 1){
                 //online
             }else{
                 //offline
             }

         }else{
             //offline
         }
     });
 },10000);
}
```